# Momentum squared in QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, momentum

I have problems understanding how the square of the momentum operator should look like in QFT.
Very likely, I'm making some mistakes somewhere but I'm not sure about it.

Let us consider a simplified setting of a 1-dimensional QFT.
Starting from a position representation and then writing the fields in momentum space, thus using the corresponding ladder operators, the momentum operator (not squared) is simply written as
$$
  \hat{p}
  = - i \hbar \int_{-\infty}^\infty \text{d} x ~ \Psi^\dagger(x) \partial \Psi(x)
  = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \text{d} p ~ a^\dagger(p) p a(p)
$$
where I skipped on the intermediate steps in which I Fourier transformed the fields and played with the algebra making a Dirac delta appear, reducing everything to the last expression.

Now, let us focus on the last expression, the one with the ladder operators.
I want to place $p^2$ rather than $p$ inside the integral and check what happens.
In particular, I would like to recover something like $(\hat{p})^2$.
I get
$$
  \int_{-\infty}^\infty \text{d} p ~ a^\dagger(p) p^2 a(p)
  = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \text{d} p_1 ~ \text{d} p_2 ~ a^\dagger(p_1) p_1 \delta(p_1 - p_2) p_2 a(p_2)
  = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \text{d} p_1 ~ \text{d} p_2 ~ a^\dagger(p_1) p_1 [a(p_1) a^\dagger(p_2) - a^\dagger(p_2) a(p_1)] p_2 a(p_2),
$$
where I let a Dirac delta appear and have used the commutation relation between ladder operators.
Expanding the square brackets, I get a term which I can indeed write as $(\hat{p})^2$, but I get another term as well.
That is,
$$
  \int_{-\infty}^\infty \text{d} p ~ a^\dagger(p) p^2 a(p)
  = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \text{d} p_1 ~ a^\dagger(p_1) p_1 a(p_1) \int_{-\infty}^\infty \text{d} p_2 ~ a^\dagger(p_2) p_2 a(p_2)
  - \int_{-\infty}^\infty \text{d} p_1 ~ \text{d} p_2 ~ a^\dagger(p_1) p_1 a^\dagger(p_2) a(p_1) p_2 a(p_2).
$$
I wasn't expecting this second term.
Unless I made some mistakes somewhere (please, let me know), since I would interpret the expression on the left as $\hat{p^2}$ (the operator associated with $p^2$), and since the first term on the right is $\hat{p}^2$ (operator squared), I would read this expression by saying that $\hat{p^2} \neq \hat{p}^2$.

Is this correct?
Am I missing something?